# how do i make this loop in the html file on app script work only per row and not cell?

Tags: javascript, css, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

sheet / app script code i'm working with:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/117Qv89zyKjlUqR_IAb_GJxdJwo64xZ9yiPOTm73baUU/edit#gid=0

https://script.google.com/u/0/home/projects/1g3RRz1kK6CM4PoW55A_O1Fzo-llbUq0M61WNiuKaftFIGRYYrf89vDF1/edit

I'm looping to get all the rows in a given range into a HTML table then put in an email. I've done this before only using app script but now I'm tiring to learn to work strictly from the HTML file since it's cleaner and readable. I'm turning this app script loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    cells = data[i];
    table = table + "<tr>";
    for (var u = 0; u < cells.length; u++) {
      table = table + `<td style="background-color:${backgrounds[i][u]};height:40px;width:100px;text-align:center;font-family:Oswald">` + cells[u] + "</td>";
    }
  }
```

into this HTML

```
      <tbody>
        
          <? for (var i = 0; i < tableRangeValues.length; i++){
            
            cells = tableRangeValues[i];
            for (var u = 0; u < cells.length; u++) {
          
          ?> 
          <!-- each td is a column -->
          <tr> 
            <td style= "background-color:<?= backgrounds[i][u]?>;height:40px;width:100px;text-align:center;font-family:Oswald"><?= cells[0] ?></td>
            <td style= "background-color:<?= backgrounds[i][u]?>;height:40px;width:100px;text-align:center;font-family:Oswald"><?= cells[1] ?></td>
            <td style= "background-color:<?= backgrounds[i][u]?>;height:40px;width:100px;text-align:center;font-family:Oswald"><?= cells[2] ?></td>
            <td style= "background-color:<?= backgrounds[i][u]?>;height:40px;width:100px;text-align:center;font-family:Oswald"><?= cells[3] ?></td>
          </tr>
          
          <?} } ?>

        
      </tbody>
```

the problem is in the for (var u = 0; u < cells.length; u++) because the row has 4 cells and that would explain why each row repeats 4 times when executed. This same code in app script like i mentioned did not repeat returning the row, so i'm assuming it's a syntax error i dido on the html.

I only want the loop to give out the row once, this is what I've been using before and it works great, EXCEPT it does not return the cell color on google sheets in the table returned from the HTML in the email.

```
      <tbody>
        
          <? for (var i = 0; i < tableRangeValues.length; i++) {row = tableRangeValues[i];?> 
          <tr>
            <td><?= row[0] ?></td>
            <td><?= row[1] ?></td>
            <td><?= row[2] ?></td>
            <td><?= row[3] ?></td>
          </tr>
          
          <?} ?>

        
      </tbody>
```

the "u" loop is how i get to the color of each cell, but from my understanding, the u loop also causes the row to repeat per cell. I can't figure out my sytnax error.

Any feedback is appreciated, i'm still learning html and using javascript functions within

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Google Apps Script, can we display a data in the HTML page as soon as somebody enters that data into Google spreadsheet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65817247/using-google-apps-script-can-we-display-a-data-in-the-html-page-as-soon-as-some)

Answer (score 2):

You can split your loop into multiple scriptlets

```
<tbody>
    <? for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { ?>
        <tr>
            <? 
                cells = data[i];
                
                for (var u = 0; u < cells.length; u++) {
            ?>
                <td style="background-color:<?= backgrounds[i][u] ?>;height:40px;width:100px;text-align:center;font-family:Oswald">
                    <?= cells[u] ?>
                </td>
            <?
                }
            ?>
        </tr>
    <? } ?>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Thank you yes, this is worked perfectly. I tried to split the loop before but I didn’t know how to place the <? ?> properly around the functions/loop.